# Scale down, then fit parent

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

How can I scale down a div, and then make it fit the parent? My aim here is to make everything inside that div a bit smaller, like a zoom out effect, but scaling causes empty space around the div.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/we7mux02/2/

```
<html>
<body>
<div
  style="width: 100%;
         transform: scale(0.7);
         background-color: blue;">
  <span style="font-size: 10em;">

    This is a large and long text...

  </span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

PS: A former employee designed a website, but everyhing (buttons, text, table, spaces) is much bigger than I like. I want to make everything about %20 smaller, like when I zoomed out using ctrl+wheel key combo.

Comment: scale is a visual effect so you will always have these gap ... instead change properties like font-size, height,width, etc

Comment: `body { zoom: 0.8; }`

Comment: @JamesLalor Sadly this website must have to work on firefox and firefox doesn't support zoom property.

Comment: @TemaniAfif I'm thinking I may do it using transform: matrix(????) but can't figure out how...

Comment: no need matrix, you will have the same effect with a more complex syntax

Comment: `transform: scale(0.8); transform-origin: 0 0;` - However, the best way is simply to go through and modify the CSS and make it the way you like, using shortcuts like this will not always give the desired effect.

Comment: @JamesLalor that just moves the div to top left, and moves spaces to down and right.

Comment: You’re better off changing font sizes etc to how you want them than trying to do something with scale

Comment: Using things like zoom and transform are never going to be as nice as styling properly so if you cannot be bothered to restyle the site to be how you want it then you have to live with the limitations of trying to use a quick and dirty hack